# DotNet failing Docker build

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have a longtime Dockerfile that worked just fine.  Then recently I started getting build errors:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:sdk AS build-env
WORKDIR /app

# Copy csproj and restore as distinct layers
COPY MycompanyDAL/*.csproj ./
COPY MycompanyDAL/NuGet.config ./
RUN dotnet restore

# Copy everything else and build
COPY MycompanyDAL/. ./
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out

# Build runtime image

FROM microsoft/dotnet:aspnetcore-runtime
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-env /app/out .

ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:8080
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "MycompanyDAL.dll"]
```

which gave the errors:

```
   docker build -t icverify-data-access .
[+] Building 1.4s (5/5) FINISHED                                                                                                                                                                          
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                                                 0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 512B                                                                                                                                                                 0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                                                    0.0s
 => => transferring context: 139B                                                                                                                                                                    0.0s
 => CANCELED [internal] load metadata for docker.io/microsoft/dotnet:aspnetcore-runtime                                                                                                              1.2s
 => ERROR [internal] load metadata for docker.io/microsoft/dotnet:sdk                                                                                                                                1.2s
 => [auth] microsoft/dotnet:pull token for registry-1.docker.io                                                                                                                                      0.0s
------
 > [internal] load metadata for docker.io/microsoft/dotnet:sdk:
------
failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to create LLB definition: pull access denied, repository does not exist or may require authorization: server message: insufficient_scope: authorization failed
```

I then updated to:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/runtime AS base
WORKDIR /app

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk AS build
WORKDIR /src

#FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0.10 AS build-env
#WORKDIR /app

# Copy csproj and restore as distinct layers
COPY MycompanyDAL/*.csproj ./
COPY MycompanyDAL/NuGet.config ./
RUN dotnet restore

# Copy everything else and build
FROM base AS publish
COPY MycompanyDAL/. ./
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out


# Build runtime image

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=base /app/out .

ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:8080
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "MycompanyDAL.dll"]
```

But this gives the same error. I am able to pull those mcr manually but it doesn't fix the problem:

```
docker pull mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0
```

Comment: Can you add the exact error message you get now to the post? One thing I noticed is that your publish steps has `FROM base` which I would expect to fail since base is the runtime image,  not the SDK. It should probably be `FROM build as publish`. Your final step also copies from base rather than from publish. I recommend getting the build to work with the old Dockerfile and new images and only when that works, you can restructure the Dockerfile.

Comment: updated to show full error message

Comment: I also changed line 16 'FROM base AS publish' to 'FROM build AS publish' but get the same results

Comment: #1 What are your o.s characteristics? #2 Share us the log of `journalctl -fu docker.service` just when you detect the error.

Comment: this is on OS X 11.6

Comment: `[auth] microsoft/dotnet` sounds like it's still looking for the old images on docker hub. Are you sure docker is using the right Dockerfile?

Comment: I am running from the project root as before.  Running 'docker build -t icverify-data-access .' from command line and from within JetBrains Rider

Comment: I asked a fellow developer to use that Dockerfile and it worked for them.  So for some reason an old Dockerfile is being used by my local.  thanks for the help!

Comment: What about the docker daemon log? Sometimes low level errors are showed in that log, not in the build log.

Comment: I haven't found the logs on my Mac for this yet..hopefully I can find them and the cause of this.

Comment: Update your question or answer it

Comment: I accepted the answer from @HansKilian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of issues with your Dockerfile which I've fixed here

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet AS base
WORKDIR /app

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk AS build
WORKDIR /src

# Copy csproj and restore as distinct layers
COPY MycompanyDAL/*.csproj ./
COPY MycompanyDAL/NuGet.config ./
RUN dotnet restore

# Copy everything else and build
FROM build AS publish
COPY MycompanyDAL/. ./
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out

# Build runtime image
FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /src/out .

ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:8080
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "MycompanyDAL.dll"]
```

Comment: appreciate the effort but still get the same CANCELED and ERROR failures

Comment: failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to create LLB definition: pull access denied, repository does not exist or may require authorization: server message: insufficient_scope: authorization failed